# Debugging Android Widget Code In Eclipse

Tags: android, android-emulator, android-widget

I am starting with Android programming with the help of [Unlocking Android / Manning](http://www.manning.com/ableson/) which came from Santa and is a pretty good book. After running a few little tests and examples, I'm moving towards developing the concepts for my own application.

I want my App to execute as a Home Widget and I'm using [this example](http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2009/04/introducing-home-screen-widgets-and.html) as my model to get started.

While I am able to load and run in the Android ADB emulator the code example in the example's Wiktionoary which is a normal Android App. I am not able to run, but only load into the emulator the Widget version of that code named SimpleWiktionary.

Am I am able to debug Android Home Widgets with the emulator? If so, what am I missing on starting/activating the Widget or having it show up in the Apps window?

T, Kenny

Comment: Debugging android widgets is almost same as debugging any normal app. You can follow this link for a step by step info about how to go about it. [How to debug android widgets in eclipse](http://tech.shantanugoel.com/2010/06/14/how-to-debug-android-widgets.html "How to debug android widgets in eclipse")

Comment: Try using the DDMS. in eclipse choose window->open perspective->DDMS

Comment: One more thing must beware, I found out if your emulator started before you open Eclipse, then it will never fall into your breakpoint no matter how many time you press F11. Try to close the emulator, and inside Eclipse, go to debug again. Then the emulator only can be attached into your IDE.

Comment: I noticed that sometimes i can't see the process of my app in the DDMS>Devices view so i cannot debug the processes. When I deploy the app to the device, it is being uploaded and installed successfully but that's it. The only process in can see in "Devices" is "com.google.android.apps.uploader". BTW, i am deploying to a real device (htc desire), not to the emulator. any ideas?

Comment: I just realized that after restarting the phone, the process is enlisted again. so this is a workaround, maybe there is a faster way to "get back to normal" ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Widgets don't show up with icons like most other applications would.  To add one to the home screen, long press on the background wallpaper and you should see a context menu pop-up that will allow you to add a widget to the screen.  If you AndroidManifest.xml is set up correctly, your widget should be shown in the menu.

You should be able to debug it by setting breakpoints in Eclipse like you would for debugging any other Android app.  However, if your widget isn't displayed on the home screen, none of the code will be executed.

Comment: Awesome. I missed that part about the long click. Thanks!

Comment: When I use my exported and signed APK file the widgets works perfectly. But when I simply run the project in eclipse I do not see any widget installed. What can be the problem?