# Break points in Android

Tags: android, android-emulator

I marked a few break points and launched the debugger, but after the application is installed, the break points don't get the "v" sign, and the debugger doesn't seem to stop when reaching to them! I really don't know what I'm missing here. Could it be related to the fact that it's an app widget application? I didn't have this issue with other applications...
I'm using the emulator, if it matters somehow.
Thanks.

Comment: Which debugger are you using? Are you in Eclipse?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is your application set to `false` for `debuggable` in your manifest? It shouldn't be in there at all or set to `true`.

```
<application android:debuggable="true" >
```

Also try to use this in the `onEnabled()`:

```
android.os.Debug.waitForDebugger();
```

Another way could be by using the DDMS perspective and selecting the widget from the list of processes.

This [link](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2015567/935627) might be helpful as well.

Comment: Where do I put the waitForDebugger call? By the way, I don't have a main activity, because it's an app widget. Should I have one?

Comment: Place it in your `onEnabled()` method.

Answer (score 0):

Check that you do not have "Skip all breakpoints" set in Eclipse. Run -> Skip All Breakpoints.  If that is set, Eclipse allows you to set breakpoints, but does not stop at them.